# Can't change login logo & css - older plugin data blocking?

Tags: plugins, css, database, wp-login-form

I'm having problem chancing the login logo & css in the wordpress standard login.
I must previusly had an old plugin or something, because it's using an old image.

Now I have addedd the php  code to it to the functions.php, to change these, but the old settings are overwriting it.

I found this data in the "OPTIONS" settings in my database; and now I have no idea what to do, I do not know who/what has placed the data there, and I can't find any settings (except editing directly to the database) to change/delete the data (but should I?)
[image]

Is somebody recognizing this? or know what to do?

Comment: Those database entries are likely from a theme or plugin. Check your plugins list for anything that looks related to customizing the login screen. You could also make a small change to the `option_name`, which should cause the styling to no longer apply. If you have a staging environment, you can also change the theme to a default theme, and see if the login styling goes away.

Comment: @Caleb good idea! - I'll do that!

Answer (score 1):

Found it!

If you are googling ***ypyp-sym-tsym***, almost nothing comes up, so I'm adding the answer here, in case somebody else stumbles upon this issue.

The plugin that added this was yellowpencil (ypyp), now known as [Visual CSS style editor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/yellow-pencil-visual-theme-customizer/)